# Cant connect to FTP with newly created account

Tags: linux, ssh, ftp

I am trying to connect to a new user account I created via SSH with the command

```
useradd -s /bin/false -d /home/username james
```

I added/edited the password via SSH with the command

```
passwd james
```

When trying to connect to my server using this user and pass via FileZilla I get the following error messages.

```
Response:   331 User James OK. Password required
Command:    PASS *****
Response:   530 Login authentication failed
Error:  Critical error
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

When I try to login with this user/pass through SFTP I get the following error messages

```
Status: Connected to domain.com
Error:  Connection closed by server with exitcode 1
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

Either way it seems it doesn't allow me to use this newuser anywhere.

My server details

```
Linux 2.6.18-308.11.1.el5 GNU/Linux
(Red Hat 4.1.2-52)
Centos
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`?  There are several settings in there that may disallow SSH login for the user you created.

Comment: Do you want to block the user for SSH, but accept for FTP? Or should both be allowed to access the server?

Comment: None of these answers work. I don't believe anybody should be awarded the bounty. The points should be returned back to my account.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding FTP, the FTP server commonly used on Linux systems requires users to have a shell that's listed in the file `/etc/shells`. For example, this [online ftpd man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ftpd) says that, among other things, "The user must have a standard shell returned by getusershell(3).". The [page for getusershell()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getusershell) shows that it reads shells from `/etc/shells`.

You could probably make FTP work adding `/bin/false` to `/etc/shells`. Your Linux system might have a more suitable shell available, like `/usr/sbin/nologin`.

Regarding SFTP, the ssh server normally provides SFTP service by by invoking a program called `sftp-server`. If you examine the server's `sshd_config` file, you'll probably find a line like this:

```
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

sshd runs the subsystem program as a shell command, using the user's shell. If you set the user's shell to `/bin/false`, then sshd ends up running the command:

```
/bin/false -c /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

/bin/false ignores its command-line arguments and exits with code 1, so the SFTP client's session drops immediately after it starts.

sshd has an internal SFTP server component that can be used instead of the external program. The usual way of limiting SSH access to SFTP for some users is to set up a `Match` group within `sshd_config`, forcing the `internal-sftp` command for certain classes of users. Here are a couple examples of that:

- http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/SFTP#SFTP-only_Accounts
- https://serverfault.com/questions/354615/allow-sftp-but-disallow-ssh

Comment: group is not necessary. We can apply the match rule to a single user. right?

Answer (score 0):

Dont use "-s /bin/false". Use "-s /sbin/nologin" instead and it should be fine.

Comment: There are two answers here at the moment. The other one might be fuller, but this gets to the point quicker. Mind you, while this should help with the sftp problem, it's not obvious which ftp server is in use, so it might not help there.

Comment: This solution doesn't do anything for SFTP access. For a normally configured SSH server, you need a valid shell to start SFTP. You need to change the sshd configuration to permit SFTP without a valid shell.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your account password hasn't expired.   Mine did, and Filezilla exited with error code 1.

After logging onto the server and updating the account password (prompted immediately after connecting), I am now able to connect with SFTP & Filezilla.

Answer (score 0):

Probably is a password related issue, check account

```
chage -l <user>
```

account must not be expired.

Answer (score 0):

FTP doesn't allow /usr/sbin/nologin user

Response:   220 Welcome to the Scent Library's File Service.
Command:    USER ftpuser
Response:   331 Please specify the password.
Command:    PASS ******
Response:   530 Login incorrect.

filezilla 530 error - but password is correct

vsftpd: 530 Login incorrect

530 Login or password incorrect!

How can I connect via FTP using FileZilla? I get a 530 error.

Response: 220 Welcome to Test FTP service.
Command: USER ftpuser
Response: 331 Please specify the password.
Command: PASS ******
Response: 530 Login incorrect.
Error: Critical error
Error: Could not connect to server

Change user's shell

usermod -s /usr/sbin/nologin username

Then edit "/etc/shells" file and add this line
/usr/sbin/nologin

Answer (score -5):

In order to connect to the server using ftp, you also need to run a ftp server / service or daemon.
An example of such ftp server is "vsftpd"
After installing it, you will also need to configure it and allow anonymous ftp access or ftp access to existing users
You will find the configuration file in the path "/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf"

The below link might be useful for you --

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-vsftpd-on-centos-6--2

Comment: Both of the OP's connection attempts indicate that he is connecting to a server. And he's not using anonymous FTP.